# Burnsides Theorem Application - Necklace

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Having a lot of trouble understanding this question: ***How many different necklaces can be made from eight black beads and four white beads?***

**What I know:**

Burnsides Theorem is given by: $$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} |\operatorname{fix}_{\Omega} (g)|$$

8+4=12 and this corresponds to the *Dihedral group* of order 12 (I use the notation $D_{2n})$ so I will note this as $D_{24}$, also known as the symmetric 12-gon.

So we know that $|G|=24$ and the total number of necklace configurations is given by $\binom{12}{4}=495$ so I'm guessing we have to $Fix(e)=495$? But I'm unsure how to apply the rest of Burnsides theorem from here and work out the configurations of rotations and reflections.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Think about the rotations and reflections of the dodecagon, and consider how each acts on its vertices.

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with visualising, this is known as Fix(g) right? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Make/buy a small dodecahedron. I did for, *e.g.*, my module on the group theory of virology when I was an undergraduate; it helped considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that  we have dihedral symmetry  we suppose we are  working with
bracelets (naming convention by OEIS).   This requires the cycle index
$Z(D_{12})$ of  the dihedral  group $D_{12}.$ We  have for  the cyclic
group that

$$Z(C_{12}) = \sum_{d|12} \varphi(d) a_d^{12/d}
= \frac{1}{12}
(a_1^{12} + a_2^6 + 2 a_3^4 + 2 a_4^3 + 2 a_6^2 + 4  a_{12}).$$

We get twelve  more permutations corresponding to flips  about an axis
passing through opposite slots or opposite edges, for a result of

$$Z(D_{12}) = \frac{1}{24}
(a_1^{12} + a_2^6 + 2 a_3^4 + 2 a_4^3 + 2 a_6^2 + 4  a_{12})
+ \frac{1}{24} ( 6 a_1^2 a_2^5 + 6 a_2^6).$$

By  the Polya  Enumeration  Theorem  (PET) we  are  interested in  the
quantity

$$[B^8 W^4] Z(D_{12}; B+W).$$

Working through the terms we find

- $[B^8 W^4] (B+W)^{12} = {12\choose 8},$
- $[B^8 W^4] (B^2+W^2)^{6} = [B^4 W^2] (B+W)^{6}
  =  {6\choose 4},$
- $[B^8 W^4] 2 (B^3+W^3)^{4} = 0$
- $[B^8 W^4] 2 (B^4+W^4)^{3} = [B^2 W] 2 (B+W)^{3}
  = 2 {3\choose 2}$
- $[B^8 W^4] 2 (B^6+W^6)^{2} = 0$
- $[B^8 W^4] 4 (B^{12}+W^{12}) = 0$

We get from the reflections

- $[B^8 W^4] 6 (B+W)^2 (B^2+W^2)^5
  \\ = [B^6 W^4] 6 (B^2+W^2)^5 + [B^7 W^3] 12 (B^2+W^2)^5 +
  [B^8 W^2] 6 (B^2+W^2)^5
  \\ = [B^3 W^2] 6 (B+W)^5 + [B^4 W] 6 (B+W)^5
  \\ = 6 {5\choose 3} + 6 {5\choose 4}$
- $[B^8 W^4] 6 (B^2+W^2)^{6} = [B^4 W^2] 6 (B+W)^{6}
  =  6 {6\choose 4}.$

Collecting everything we find for our result that it is

$$\frac{1}{24} \left({12\choose 8} + {6\choose 4} + 2 {3\choose 2}
+ 6{5\choose 3} + 6{5\choose 4} + 6 {6\choose 4}\right).$$

which yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{29.}$$

Comment: Of topic, is this one also doable by PET or Burnside: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314788/let-p-be-an-odd-prime-number-how-many-p-element-subsets-of-1-2-3-4-ldo/314867#314867

Comment: It appears that the answer is yes, consult e.g. [MSE 2894653](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894653/).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I haven't been introduced to this theorem/notation before would you mind explaining what the $a_{n}$ to the power, variables are. Thanks.

Comment: [Wikipedia on cycle indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) is quite useful here.