# Hyperfaces of a hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coloring the faces of a hypercube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/coloring-the-faces-of-a-hypercube)

In how many different ways, up to rotations, can we color each of the hyperfaces of a hypercube with one of $k$ colors? Consider all symmetries. I think this would involve Burnside's lemma.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5697/264).