# How do you prove a degree sequence isn't possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For example, why is the degree sequence 3,3,1,1 not possible? I said because there are only 4 vertices and if two of them have degree 3 then the other 2 must have degree 2. Is this "proving it"? What else can be said in these types of questions to be more convincing?

Comment: What you said seems convincing enough for me. In general though, degree sequences can be determined to be valid or invalid through theorems like Havel-Hakimi or [Erdős-Gallai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem).

Comment: If self-edges ([loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory))) are allowed, then the degree sequence $3,3,1,1$ can be attained.  Conventionally a self-edge is counted twice for the degree of its vertex, as this interpretation preserves the [handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) that the sum of degrees is twice the number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

While what you said was clear and convincing, one method to make the argument more concrete is to represent any possible graph by [an adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) that attains the given degrees.

As your Question implicitly frames it, the degree sequence can be ordered arbitrarily, and thus sorting it is a convenient starting point.  Any adjacency matrix would be $4\times 4$ with binary entries ($0$s and $1$s), symmetric (for undirected graphs), and have only $0$s on the diagonal (no self-edges in simple graphs).

Taking the first row/column to represent a vertex of degree $3$, we would have this:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & ? & ? \\ 1 & ? & 0 & ? \\ 1 & ? & ? & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

But as your argument notes, we are obstructed when we try to make the next vertex have degree $3$, because filling in those entries forces the two remaining vertices to have degree (at least) $2$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & ? \\ 1 & 1 & ? & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

---

A different approach to proving the nonexistence of a graph with this degree sequence would be to count the edges, $|E|$, which must be half the sum of all the degrees.  That is, $|E|=4$ if the degrees add up to $8$ as they would here.

Now the complete graph $K_4$ on four vertices only has six edges, so we can picture starting with that and [removing two edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/599871/3111), which would either be two connected edges or two unconnected edges.  The first choice leaves a degree sequence $3,2,2,1$, and the second leaves a degree sequence $2,2,2,2$.  Since neither choice gives us what we want, we get what we need!

---

Also, as @EuYu points out in a Comment, the [Erdős–Gallai theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) restricts the possible degree sequences and can be applied here to exclude the possibility of $3,3,1,1$.

To be realized as the (descending) degrees of a simple graph, nonnegative integers $d_1 \ge d_2 \ge \ldots \ge d_n$ must satisfy for each $1 \le k \le n$:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^k d_i \le k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \min(d_i,k) $$

In particular for our target degree sequence with $k=2$, $d_1 + d_2 = 6$ but:

$$2(2-1) + \min(1,3) + \min(1,4) = 4$$

and the necessary condition fails.