# Depiction of all graphs (not necessarily connected) with 6 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am searching (with no unsuccess) the WWW for a depiction of all non-isomorphic graphs with 6 vertices.

On the site http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html I found an incomplete list, but all graphs with 5 vertices (34 ones). According to the integer sequence [A000088](https://oeis.org/A000088), there should be 156 of them. A paper by Cvetkovic and Petric http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X84900335 gives all *connected* graphs with 6 vertices (112 ones).

If I take all connected graphs (112) and take all graphs with 5 vertices adding a separate node (34), then I have 146 graphs. Which 10 graphs are missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: By all *complete* graphs did you perhaps mean all *connected* graphs?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, thanks.

Comment: Given your existing work, you may find the earlier Question [Why there are 11 non-isomorphic graphs of order 4?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/why-there-are-11-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-order-4) a useful reference.  These include non-connected possibilities.

Comment: You need all connected graphs on 4 vertices (6 of them) with two separate vertices and the pair of 3-line/triangle with 3 disconnected vertices, etc. 6 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 10. To put it another way, the number of graphs on N are the sum of the number of connected graphs on N plus the number of connected  graphs on N-1 ... 1.

Comment: You may be interested to look at http://www.findstat.org/StatisticFinder/Graphs/ by the FindStat project

Answer (score 1):

We can partition the graphs by the number of connected components.

**One connected component:** There are $112$ connected graphs with $6$ vertices

**Two connected components:** There can be

- A connected component of size $1$ and a connected component of size $5$ ($1 \cdot 21 = 21$ possibilities)
- A connected component of size $2$ and a connected component of size $4$ ($\color{red}{1 \cdot 6 = 6}$ possibilities)
- A connected component of size $3$ and another connected component of size $3$ ($\color{red}{3}$ possibilities - $P_3 \sqcup P_3$, $P_3 \sqcup K_3$, or $K_3 \sqcup K_3$)

**Three connected components**: There can be

- Two connected components of size $1$ and a connected component of size $4$ ($1 \cdot 1 \cdot 6=6$ possibilities)
- A connected component of size $1$, one of size $2$, and one of size $3$ ($1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 2$ possibilities)
- Three connected components of size $2$ ($\color{red}{1}$ possibility - $P_3 \sqcup P_2 \sqcup P_2$)

**Four connected components**: There can be only be three connected components of size $1$ and one of size $3$, for $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 2$ possibilities

**Five connected components**: There can only be four connected components of size $1$ and one of size $2$, for $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 2$ possibilities

**Six connected components**: One possibility

Add these up and you get $112+21+6+3+6+2+1+2+2+1=156$ graphs.

The ones in red are the ones you are missing - they are not obtained from adding an isolated vertex to a graph with $5$ vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to systematically count is to begin with the integer partitions of six as denoting the sizes of components in your (not necessarily connected) graphs.  There are [eleven possibilities](http://www.luschny.de/math/seq/PartitionsOf6.htm).

Some of these give rise to a single (up to isomorphism) graph:

$1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$

$2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$

$2 + 2 + 1 + 1$

$2 + 2 + 2$

Some give rise to two possibilities each as three nodes can form a connected component in exactly two ways:

$3 + 1 + 1 + 1$

$3 + 2 + 1$

Then there are three possibilities for this partition:

$3 + 3$

because the two components can be non-isomorphic in one way but isomorphic in two ways.

From the [earlier Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/why-there-are-11-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-order-4) we see that there are six connected graphs on four vertices, so each of these gives six possibilities:

$4 + 1 + 1$

$4 + 2$

Then we get down to the cases you previously considered:

$5 + 1$ (a connected component of five vertices and one extra node)

$6$ (a connected component of six vertices)

There are respectively $21$ and $112$ of these cases (see [OEIS A001349](https://oeis.org/A001349), Number of connected graphs with n nodes).  The previous small cases numbered $23$, and $23+21+112= 156$.