# is there a certain number of cut sets of a graph with n vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Firstly, how many cut sets do graphs have? Do they have more than one ? If so, is there a way of knowing how many of them there are? Also, what does it mean for a disconnecting set of edges to not be a cut set? Isn't disconnecting the graph the main definition of a cut set ?

Comment: Some graphs on $n$ vertices are already disconnected.  You should try some examples, [say with four vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/why-there-are-11-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-order-4), to get a better understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: One easily finds a [definition of cut set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) in Wikipedia, among other places on the Web.

Comment: the definitions contradict with the answers given to problems by my professor

Comment: You are not giving me enough information to guess what's inconsistent or how to resolve your confusion.  Perhaps the exercises involve the *minimum* size of a cut set for particular graphs?

Comment: Maybe consider block-diagonal examples for a simple-to-understand example.

Answer (score 3):

A *cut set* is [the set of edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) between the two parts of a bipartition of the nodes in a graph.  So if a graph has $n$ nodes, there are $2^{n-1} - 1$ ways to partition those nodes into two nonempty subsets (bipartitions).

Unfortunately the number of *cut sets* is not quite in one-to-one correspondence with those bipartitions (which we easily counted).  In particular, if the graph $G$ on $n$ nodes is *disconnected*, there can be various bipartitions that give us the same *empty* cut set.

So $2^{n-1} - 1$ is an upper bound on the number of cut sets, but it is not tight.  Consider [the examples of graphs on four nodes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/why-there-are-11-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-order-4), and see if you can find a pattern for *connected graphs* versus *disconnected graphs*.

While every cut set is a "disconnecting set of edges" (removing them guarantees a disconnect graph will result), not every disconnecting set of edges can be realized as a cut set.  This is true even if we assume graph $G$ is connected.  Again you should be able to pick out an example of this using graphs on four nodes.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** this hint may make most sense if you have studied the *spectral clustering* connection to graph cuts.

---

To build some intuition on this consider the masking matrix $${\bf M}= {\bf I}_n\otimes {\underset{m\times m \text{ block of 1:s}}{\underbrace{({\bf 1}_m{{\bf 1}_m}^T)}}}$$

Where $\otimes$ is Kronecker product. Introduce a random matrix ${\bf R}=uniform([0,1],m\times n)$. Then we reset ${\bf R = I+R+R}^T$ to ensure a symmetric matrix with large diagonal elements which is what we would expect from a candidate affinity matrix.

We can now consider $\bf A = M \circ R$ ($\circ$ Schur/Hadamard product) being a fake affinity matrix of a block-diagonal matrix from which we can construct a normalized Laplacian (${\bf D} = \text{diag}(\text{diag}({\bf A}))$):

$$\bf L = D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2}-I$$

Now maybe you have some ideas of how to proceed?

---

**EDIT** Ok maybe my hint was a bit cryptic. The next step is to calculate and sort eigenvalues and check corresponding eigenvectors. As happens the $n$ largest eigenvalues (which will be all eigenvalues $>0$) will correspond to eigenvectors which are non-zero for the $m$ elements uniquely corresponding to a particular $m\times m$ block and zero everywhere else. If you are still unsure what it means, you can experiment with switching the order of the Kronecker factors where $\bf M$ is constructed and see what happens to those eigenvectors.

Comment: Note that the OP is struggling with the *definition* of cut set, and with counting them.  It seems doubtful that they have already "studied the *spectral clustering* connection to graph cuts."

Comment: @hardmath: Depends on which angle you approach graph cuts from. If you are an engineer learning Linear Algebra, calculus and loads of continous math first and hardly any set theory or discrete maths then spectral clustering will be an obvious introduction.