# how can we determinate that exist 11 non-isomorphic graphs on 4-vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I did all the 11 graphs but how can i prove it?
I did all the grade of the vertices but im not sure how to proof that there are only 11

Comment: "how to proof that there are only 11" I would do a case-by-case analysis. Split into cases that are smaller and easier to analyse than "all graphs on 4 vertices", and make absolutely sure that you have all graphs in each case.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/why-there-are-11-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-order-4

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, in this context, "grado" should be translated as "degree", not "grade."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think that Arthur's comment is the way to go, if that doesn't convince you, you can cross-check against the number of labeled graphs.  That is, label the vertices A,B,C,D say, and consider all ways of joining them.

The adjacency matrix matrix is $4\times4$, and is completely determined by the $6$ values in the upper triangle, so there are $2^6$ labeled graphs on $4$ vertices.  Count how many labeled graphs correspond to each of your graphs.  If the total comes to $64$, you know you've got them all.

For example, one of your graphs has one edge and two isolated vertices.  There are $\binom42=6$ ways to choose the adjacent vertices, so this graph corresponds to $6$ labeled graphs.

Comment: thank you so much saul

Comment: @RobertaRuiz My pleasure.