# Calculating how many loop-free non-isomorphic undirected graphs with a specific number of vertices that exist

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, polya-counting-theory

Say you have a graph with 4 vertices, I would know that it can have a maximum of $\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix} = 6$ edges. What I'm not sure about how to find is how many ways you can connect the vertices if the graph has no loops, and is non-isomorphic.

After manually finding the ways to create these graphs, I observed the following:

| # of edges | # of graphs |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |

There must be a way to predict this with permutations/combinations, but I'm just not sure how to change the question into a way that I can calculate it.

Comment: This problem appeared at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/). I will  leave it to the experts to decide whether the question should be marked a duplicate. For $n$ vertices consult [MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088991/).